HRM recording app for android with data export option
During my workouts, I need to use compound timer. At the same time, I need to use my phone to record data from HRM monitor. There are many applications that can connect to my HRM and run in background: Strava, Polar Beat, MapMyFitness, etc.
However, not a single one of those I found and tested allow me to download/export the data. Every one of them offer some kind of obfuscated data at the end (weird analysis with zone, graph as a picture, etc.)
Is there a free app for android, that can just record and export the data to properly track workout? (any format possible, I do not care - xls, xml, csv, json,...).

MapMyFitness https://support.mapmyfitness.com/hc/en-us/articles/1500009118782-Export-Workout-Data and Strava https://support.strava.com/hc/en-us/articles/216918437-Exporting-your-Data-and-Bulk-Export allow data export

@Luciano MapMyFintess export do not contain HRM data. Strava can export the data into FIT format, but it is not obvious whether the HRM is there or not (no familiar nubers, no labels, etc.)

"Navigate to one of your Activity pages and from the more (ellipses) menu, select "Export GPX". The file will then download to your computer with the file extension ".gpx". This file will contain your GPS coordinates, timestamps, and accessory data like heart rate, cadence, and temperature." - First hit from "Export heart rate data from strava". And yes, I've used it before, it is there.

@JohnP I found your suggestion in documentation, there really should be "Export GPX" option. However it is not in my activity (maybe it is only for activites using localisation)? I can only "export original". I found alternative android application that can export csv. If I need alternative in future, I will install the Strava again and test your suggestion again. Thanks for your time.
